Как при помощи grid расположить изображение справа от текста?
Подскажите пожалуйста как расположить изображение справа от текста так, что бы оно не вылезало за пределы карточки. Получается так:
А должно выглядеть так:
Хотелось бы узнать как лучше располагать изображение в контейнере, чтобы оно не выходило за его пределы, чтобы потом получилась адаптивная вёрстка.
Вот мой код:
HTML:

  <section class="shop">
    <div class="shop__gr">
      <div class="div__1 cart">
        <h1 class="cart__shop">Фильтрующие<br> материалы </h1>
        <p>Только лучшие фильтроматериалы<br> в наличие на складах!</p>
        <button type="button" class="button__catalog__full button"><span>Подробнее </span><img class="image__but" src="/img/buttt.png"></button>
        <img class="image_catalog" src="/img/image1_catalog.png">
      </div>


      <div class="div__2 cart">
        <h1 class="cart__shop">Кондиционеры и сплит Системы </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="div__3 cart">
        <h1 class="cart__shop">Фильтрующие материалы </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="div__4 cart">
        <h1 class="cart__shop">Фильтрующие материалы </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="div__5 cart">
        <h1 class="cart__shop">Фильтрующие материалы </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="div__6 cart">
        <h1 class="cart__shop">Фильтры для вентиляции</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="div__7 cart">
        <h1 class="cart__shop">Фильтрующие материалы </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="div__8 cart">
        <h1 class="cart__shop">Фильтрующие материалы </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="div__9 cart">
        <h1 class="cart__shop">Фильтрующие материалы </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="div__10 cart">
        <h1 class="cart__shop">Фильтрующие материалы </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="div__11 cart">
        <h1 class="cart__shop">Фильтрующие материалы </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="div__12 cart">
        <h1 class="cart__shop">Фильтрующие материалы </h1>
      </div>

    </div> 


  </section>


CSS:

.button__catalog__full{
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #12e435;
  border: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.shop__gr{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.cart{
  background-color: #EBEFEC;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: grid;
}

.image_catalog{
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.div__1{
  /* grid-column-start: 0;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 0;
  grid-row-end: 2; */
  width: 670px;
  height: 376px;
  grid-area: 1/1/3/3;
  /* display: grid; */
}
 
.div__1 p{
  grid-column: 1;
}

.div__1 button{
  grid-column: 1;

}

.div__2{
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 1 / 3;
}
.div__3{
  grid-area: 1 / 4 / 1 / 4;
}
.div__4{
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 3 / 1;
}
.div__5{
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 3 / 2;
}
.div__6{
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 4 / 5;
}
.div__7{
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 6 / 3;  
}
.div__8{
  grid-area: 4 / 3 / 4 / 3;
}
.div__9{
  grid-area: 4 / 4 / 4 / 4;
}
.div__10{
  grid-area: 5 / 3 / 7 / 5;
}
.div__11{
  grid-area: 6 / 1 / 6 / 1;
}
.div_12{
  grid-area: 6 / 2 / 6 / 2;
}



Путем grid -  div__1 сделать сеткой и поставить жестко ширину для картинки и блока слева. Но не такой адаптивный вариант:


.div__1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  /* остальныe стили */
}

.image_catalog {
  justify-self: end;
  align-self: center;
}
<div class="div__1 cart">
  <div>
        <h1 class="cart__shop">Фильтрующие<br> материалы </h1>
        <p>Только лучшие фильтроматериалы<br> в наличие на складах!</p>
        <button type="button" class="button__catalog__full button"><span>Подробнее </span><img class="image__but" src="/img/buttt.png"></button>
  </div>
        <img class="image_catalog" src="/img/image1_catalog.png">
      </div>



На макете такое изображение накладывается на текст. Поэтому нужно сделать его absolute и центрировать:


.div__1 {
  position: relative;
  /*Остальные стили*/
}

.div__1-left {
  /*Обрезать по нужной ширине*/
  max-width: 50%;
}

.image_catalog {
  position: absolute;
  /* Цетроирование по вертикали */
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* Позиционирование */
  right: 0;
  /*Если картинку решат поменять нужно назначить границы*/
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 50%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
<div class="div__1 cart">
  <div class="div__1-left">
    <h1 class="cart__shop">Фильтрующие<br> материалы </h1>
      <p>Только лучшие фильтроматериалы<br> в наличие на складах!</p>
    <button type="button" class="button__catalog__full button">
      <span>Подробнее </span><img class="image__but" src="/img/buttt.png">     
    </button>
  <div>
  <img class="image_catalog" src="/img/image1_catalog.png">
</div>




К сожалению данный способ не подходит к созданию нескольких карточек, картинки почему-то прилипают к каждому новому блоку и не получается разделить их по местам.

Можно сделать, например так (картинки просто для примера):
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <article class="card">
        <div class="card-data">
            <div class="card-info">
                <h1 class="card-title">Фильтрующие материалы </h1>
                <p>Только лучшие фильтроматериалы в наличие на складах!</p>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="button__catalog__full button">
                <span>Подробнее</span>
                <img class="image__but"
                    src="https://gas-kvas.com/grafic/uploads/posts/2024-01/gas-kvas-com-p-strelka-dlya-detei-na-prozrachnom-fone-21.png">
            </button>
        </div>
        <img class="image_catalog"
            src="https://www.coolershop.ru/image/cache/catalog/filtry/Aquafor-set-b510-03-04-07-800x800.jpg">
    </article>
</body>

</html>

CSS:
*,
*::after,
*::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.card {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);

    max-width: 600px;
    min-width: 400px;
    

    background-color: #EBEFEC;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.card-data {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 15px;
}

.card-title {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.button__catalog__full {
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #12e435;
    border: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 15px;
    max-width: 160px;
    aspect-ratio: 3.5;
}

.image__but {
    width: 30px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

.image_catalog {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

Получается более адаптивная карточка, хотя нужно еще тестить. И еще нужно решить вопрос максимального и минимального размера самой карточки, и от чего он зависит, но это уже нужно решать в контексте общего макета.

А как создать такую сетку из карточек, ибо они слипаются друг с другом. Не понимаю какое свойство отвечает за то, чтобы карточки слипались. Я выделяю им область при помощи grid-area, а они вс-равно вместе.

В CSS для grid и flex лэйаутов есть семейство свойств gap, они позволяют удобно управлять отступами между ячейками. Посмотри на doka.guide, там очень хорошо расписано.
